# Can I keep my skinned dog out of danger?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

In the Shivering Isles Expansion for Oblivion, you get a quest called Ushnar's Terror. As a reward you get his skinned dog.

Is there a way to keep the dog and essentially trap it in your house so it can't get out and you can keep it?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly there is no regular way to keep the "Undead Hound" (Dog). If you are playing the PC-Version there may be some Plugins for Companions to handle your Quest-Reward.

As the Shivering Isle Wiki says:

> The hound does not respawn and can't be told to wait, so it will be stuck with you until its demise.
>   The hound is a permanent corpse, making it a useful storage device once it dies. 
>   The hound doesn't travel with you when you fast travel. Instead, its Speed is temporarily increased to 255 and it will chase after the player, occasionally causing it to lag behind.

So the only way to get Rid of it, is to multiply fast-Travel to Long-Distance Locations, or to let it Die in any preferred way oO

Link to Wiki: [Ushnar's Terror - The Skinned Hound](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Shivering:Ushnar%27s_Skinned_Hound)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question because I'm in the dark brotherhood and on this contract I have to be invisible but my dog can't be as well. so I applied poison to my sword and hit it and it stayed put.

This does not harm the hound because they are resistant to poison.

Answer (score 0):

[UESPWiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Console_Command_Tutorial#SetEssential_BaseID_.23)

> **SetEssential BaseID** #
>
> (Only works with NPC and creature IDs.)
>
> Makes the NPC or creature belonging to the ID essential or non-essential depending on the number used (1 for essential, 0 for non-essential). Be careful if you use this on a creature as it will affect every creature of that name.
>
> Example: SetEssential A288 0; removes Countess Millona Umbranox's essential flag.
>
> Notes: Be careful with this one as you can break quests if you make the wrong NPC non-essential at the wrong time, but you can also protect a quest by making a non-essential NPC essential. This will not work correctly if used on the player. The player will fall unconscious, but all controls will be disabled and the player will never regain consciousness. Use ToggleGodMode (tgm) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the "Fighters Stronghold" aka the battlehorn castle DLC, There is a secret room in the castle, if you can get Unshars Dog out of Shivering, Then go to castle and put him in the secret room and close the door. it is not technically a "Door" so the hound cannot open it.
Also if you dont have it its 1 dollar... and its also a great house+one of the biggest houses.
Also you can find the hidden room here,    http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/File:Battlehorn_Castle_Private_Quarters.jpg